# Why is function equality defined as such?

Tags: functions

In class we have been learning about functions, and that if $f:A\to B$ and $g: A^{'} \to B^{'}$, then $f=g$ if and only if $A=A^{'}$ and $B=B^{'}$ and they share the same values.

Why does $B=B^{'}$ have to be the case? Why can't we base it solely on sharing the same values, or perhaps at least the codomain containing the entire image?

Example; Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) = x^2$. Let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x \geq 0 \}$ where $g(x) = x^2$. Intuitively I would say these functions are equivalent as they share the same values, but by the definition they're not. Why?

Comment: Sometimes we *do* define functions that way. In set theory, a function $f$ is identified with its graph $\{(x, f(x)): x\in dom(f)\}$. It ultimately comes down to what you want to do, mathematically. Sometimes having an explicit codomain is important, other times it's not.

Comment: @NoahSchweber That’s not always the case in set theory though, sometimes functions are defined as $(f, A, B)$, where $f\subseteq A\times B$ is the graph, $A$ is the domain, and $B$ is the codomain. This yields a trivial way of arriving at OP’s definition of equality without being imprecise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining them this way let us ask more interesting question such as does every element of the codomain has a preimage, also known as surjective/ onto.

For the first case, $f$ does not have this property.

But for the second case, every element of the codomain does have a preimage.

So why do we study surjective function? If a function is one-to-one and onto, then we know that the inverse of a function exists.